# Using asrtoolkit's wer function but need help to plop character error rate

Tags: python

I'm trying to use asrtoolkit's wer function (https://github.com/finos/greenkey-asrtoolkit). I can get it to work on word error rate:

```
from asrtoolkit import wer
print(wer("abcd", "abce"))
```

Now I'm trying to do character error rate, for which they have the optional argument --char-level (see readme link above).

```
print(wer("abcd", "abce",char-level))
print(wer("abcd", "abce",char_level))
print(wer("abcd", "abce","char-level"))
print(wer("abcd", "abce",char-level=True))
print(wer("abcd", "abce",char_level=True))     #plus all of those with one or two dashes...
```

Where do I plop this argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use character error rate instead of word error rate, call the `cer` function instead of the `wer` function:

```py
from asrtoolkit import cer
print(cer("abcd", "abce"))
```